# Finding Minimum Distances Between Rows of Data Frames

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

Suppose I have the following two data frames:

```
set.seed(123)

df_1 <- data.frame(
  name_1 = c("john", "david", "alex", "kevin", "trevor"),
  lon = rnorm(5, mean = -74.0060, sd = 0.01),
  lat = rnorm(5, mean = 40.7128, sd = 0.01)
)

df_2 <- data.frame(
  name_2 = c("matthew", "tyler", "sebastian"),
  lon = rnorm(3, mean = -74.0060, sd = 0.01),
  lat = rnorm(3, mean = 40.7128, sd = 0.01)
)
```

**My Question:** For each person in df_1, I want to find out the person in df_2 that is situated closest to that person in df_1 and record the distance.

I am using the following function for distance calculations:

```
library(geosphere)
haversine_distance <- function(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2) {
  distHaversine(c(lon1, lat1), c(lon2, lat2))
}
```

I am now trying to create a data frame ("final") with the same number of rows as df_1 : this data frame should contain columns about the lon/lat for each person in df_1, the lon/lat of the closest person in df_2 and the corresponding distance (in meters).

I tried to solve this problem using LOOPS to loop over all combinations and store the minimum distance for each person. Here is my attempt:

```
# Create a matrix to store results
distances <- matrix(nrow = nrow(df_1), ncol = nrow(df_2))

# calculate the distances
for (i in 1:nrow(df_1)) {
    for (j in 1:nrow(df_2)) {
        distances[i, j] <- haversine_distance(df_1$lon[i], df_1$lat[i], df_2$lon[j], df_2$lat[j])
    }
}

# find  closest person 
closest <- apply(distances, 1, which.min)

# Create final
final <- data.frame(
    name_1 = df_1$name_1,
    lon_1 = df_1$lon,
    lat_1 = df_1$lat,
    name_2 = df_2$name_2[closest],
    lon_2 = df_2$lon[closest],
    lat_2 = df_2$lat[closest],
    distance = distances[cbind(1:nrow(df_1), closest)]
)
```

The final answer looks like this:

```
  name_1     lon_1    lat_1    name_2     lon_2    lat_2  distance
1   john -74.01160 40.72995 sebastian -74.00199 40.73067  814.8114
2  david -74.00830 40.71741     tyler -74.00240 40.70724 1236.4946
3   alex -73.99041 40.70015     tyler -74.00240 40.70724 1283.3369
4  kevin -74.00529 40.70593     tyler -74.00240 40.70724  284.3799
5 trevor -74.00471 40.70834     tyler -74.00240 40.70724  229.9678
```

The code seems to have run without errors - **but can someone please tell me if I have done this correctly?**

Thanks!

Comment: your final answer appears to be correct. Are you requesting a different approach?

Comment: @langtang: thank you for your reply! I am trying to confirm if I have done this logically. in the past I have written code that runs without errors but the results are not always correct. thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is to use a `cross_join()`

```
cross_join(df_1, df_2) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(dist=distHaversine(c(lon.x, lat.x), c(lon.y, lat.y))) %>% 
  group_by(name_1) %>% 
  filter(dist==min(dist))
```

OR

```
cross_join(df_1, df_2) %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(dist=distHaversine(c(lon.x, lat.x), c(lon.y, lat.y))) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  slice_min(order_by = dist, by = name_1)
```

Output (under either option):

```
  name_1 lon.x lat.x name_2    lon.y lat.y  dist
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 john   -74.0  40.7 sebastian -74.0  40.7  815.
2 david  -74.0  40.7 tyler     -74.0  40.7 1236.
3 alex   -74.0  40.7 tyler     -74.0  40.7 1283.
4 kevin  -74.0  40.7 tyler     -74.0  40.7  284.
5 trevor -74.0  40.7 tyler     -74.0  40.7  230.
```

Comment: @ langtang: thank you so much for your answer! I am working on a related question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76081342/r-finding-out-5-closest-points-to-each-point - can you please take a look at it if you have time? thank you so much!